# Android invalid resource directory name:appcompat_v7\bin\res crunch

Tags: android, aapt

My app add the v7 lib under the libraries dependency. When I run the build script(**under Eclipse**), I got the following error:

```
[mergemanifest] Manifest merger disabled. Using project manifest only.
     [echo] Handling aidl files...
     [aidl] No AIDL files to compile.
     [echo] ----------
     [echo] Handling RenderScript files...
     [echo] ----------
     [echo] Handling Resources...
     [aapt] Generating resource IDs...
     [aapt] invalid resource directory name: D:\Workspace\appcompat_v7\bin\res crunch
```

I tried everything, but can't figure out how to solve it. Any help?
This happens with all libraries I added, so I'm forced to use the .jar instead but v7 appears has no jar.

Comment: If you are just starting, why not use Android's official IDE, Android Studio?

Comment: Because this app is an old project and I did not migrate yet to AStudio. But until then, I need to fix this because I cannot use v7 otherwise.

Comment: Are you using the and script to build your project? If so, make sure you've created the build.xml script for the v7 as well

Comment: I have same problem with a project which has ant build scripts but I also imported it into Android Studio